# lag-1 difference between columns of a data frame or matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, difference

I would like to make a function that it would calculate the lag-1 difference between multiple columns in R.

For example, my data frame looks like that:

```
  id  Value  Value2 Value3 Value4  
A234     10     15     NA     NA 
B345     20     25     25     30 
C500     20     25     15     NA
```

I would like the function to take the difference between the 5th and 4th column. Then, the 4th and 3rd column and then last the 3rd and 2nd column.

I am aware of two previous Q & A on taking difference between rows:

- [R how can I calculate difference between rows in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16212097/4891738)
- [New matrix containing difference between row elements of original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12052185/4891738)

But I can't adapt the solution to deal with columns. Sorry if this is too simple. I am newbie in R.

---

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A234", "B345", "C500"), Value = c(10L, 
20L, 20L), Value2 = c(15L, 25L, 25L), Value3 = c(NA, 25L, 15L
), Value4 = c(NA, 30L, NA)), .Names = c("id", "Value", "Value2", 
"Value3", "Value4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### data frame

> I would like the function to take the difference between the 5th and 4th column. Then, the 4th and 3rd column and then last the 3rd and 2nd column.

We can do

```
cbind(df[1], df[3:5] - df[2:4])
#    id Value2 Value3 Value4
#1 A234      5     NA     NA
#2 B345      5      0      5
#3 C500      5    -10     NA
```

`df[3:5] - df[2:4]` works because element-wise arithmetic is well-defined in R between two data frames of the same size. In particular, column names of `DF1 - DF2` would inherits column names of the first data frame `DF1`.

We can also use negative indexing:

```
df0 <- df[-1]  ## drop "id" column
cbind(df[1], df0[-1] - df0[-length(df0)])
#    id Value2 Value3 Value4
#1 A234      5     NA     NA
#2 B345      5      0      5
#3 C500      5    -10     NA
```

**caveat:**

Since a data frame may store data of different types in different columns, I advise that you first check its columns before trying to take difference, otherwise arithmetic operation may be invalid. With your example data frame, we can do

```
sapply(df, class)
#         id       Value      Value2      Value3      Value4 
#"character"   "integer"   "integer"   "integer"   "integer"
```

So taking difference between the last 4 columns is valid.

Here is another example with `iris` dataset:

```
sapply(iris, class)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

The last column is a "factor" that can not be used for valid arithmetic.

Note that we use `class` rather than `mode` for type checking on each data frame column, as it does a more comprehensive check. See [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52240201/4891738) for more explanation.

---

### matrix

A matrix can only hold a single type of data. Use `mode` to check data type to ensure that arithmetic is valid. For example, you can't do arithmetic on "character" data.

Suppose we have a "numeric" matrix

```
set.seed(0)
A <- round(matrix(runif(25), 5, 5), 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] 0.90 0.20 0.06 0.77 0.78
#[2,] 0.27 0.90 0.21 0.50 0.93
#[3,] 0.37 0.94 0.18 0.72 0.21
#[4,] 0.57 0.66 0.69 0.99 0.65
#[5,] 0.91 0.63 0.38 0.38 0.13

mode(A)
#[1] "numeric"
```

We can use the following to take difference between column 2 and column 1, column 3 and column 2, etc:

```
A[, -1, drop = FALSE] - A[, -ncol(A), drop = FALSE]
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
#[1,] -0.70 -0.14 0.71  0.01
#[2,]  0.63 -0.69 0.29  0.43
#[3,]  0.57 -0.76 0.54 -0.51
#[4,]  0.09  0.03 0.30 -0.34
#[5,] -0.28 -0.25 0.00 -0.25
```

Comment: just a little variation ; `cbind(df[1], df[-1]-cbind(x = 0, df[c(-1,-5)]))` +1

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this but, assuming your data.frame is called df it could be as simple as
`cbind(df$Value2-df$Value,df$Value3-df$Value2,df$Value4-df$Value3)`
You could rap than in a function very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your purposes Zheyuan Li's answer is the simplest and most elegant. However, I just wanted to show how you could also solve this using my goto function for differences between values, `diff`, from package `Matrix`. In my answer I have retained the order you requested (col 5 - col4, col 4 - col 3, etc.).

```
# Load package
library(Matrix)    

# Create a dataframe of differences
cbind(df[1], rev(as.data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, diff, 1)))))
#    id Value4 Value3 Value2
#1 A234     NA     NA      5
#2 B345      5      0      5
#3 C500     NA    -10      5
```